# Cannot start .exe file propetly because config

Tags: batch-file

So...I have "launcher"..
Its .bat file and i want it to start /ffa/server.exe
but..In ffa/ i have config file.

When i start server via launcher it starts server but it makes new config file
in directory of launcher..How can i fix this?

And "server" its: https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar

```
start cmd /k %~dp0\ffa\server.exe
```

Please help me, its really frustrating..Thanks <3!

Comment: Why are you using cmd.exe? You can just use your executable directly.  Your best option is to use the /D option without cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pushd to move to the correct directory, start the server, and then pop back:

```
pushd %~dp0\ffa
start cmd /k server.exe
popd
```

I'm not familiar with the exact folder structure you're working with, and exactly how you call the script, but you definitely could use push/popd for this.

Comment: Just use the /D option of the start command and get rid of cmd.

Answer (score 1):

There are more possible solutions to change working directory of started command prompt window:

In calling script

```
pushd %~dp0\ffa
start "" cmd /k server.exe
popd
```

In started `cmd` itself: note [properly escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `&` character (see [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html))

```
start "" cmd /k pushd %~dp0\ffa^&server.exe
```

Using [`/D` parameter of `start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

```
start "" /D "%~dp0\ffa" cmd /k server.exe
```